# How to send/post the JSON request in windowsphone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, httprequest

Anyone knows how to send the request using JSON content in windowsphone. I had the JSON parameters how to post it.

Answer (score 4):

Simply serialize the data in JSON, and write it as a POST request to the server. Here's how I do it in one of my apps:

```
private static IObservable<T> GetDataAsync<T, TRequest>(TRequest input, string address)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";

    var getRequestStream = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(
        request.BeginGetRequestStream,
        request.EndGetRequestStream);

    var getResponse = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
        request.BeginGetResponse,
        request.EndGetResponse);

    return getRequestStream()
                .SelectMany(stream =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                            writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // Intentionally ignored.
                    }

                    return getResponse();
                })
                .Select(webResponse =>
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! may i know how to post json data  eg: JSONDATA:{"metaData":{"appId":"..","appVersion":".."},"searchData":{"type":"KEY_SEARCH","term":"07391905","latitude":-999.0,"longitude":-999.0,"format":"JSON","filterValues":[]},"userData":{"authority":"USER","encryption":"3"}}

Comment: please help me, how to post the above json data. i had url in .php

Comment: If you fail to understand the absolute basics, you should go back and practice Hello World again.